# Github Pages Unsupported Jekyll Theme

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-theme

I've been trying to use a Jekyll theme from bootstrap called jekyll-theme-clean-blog, and everytime I publish it on Github I receive an email saying,
 *"You are attempting to use a Jekyll theme, "jekyll-theme-clean-blog", which is not supported by GitHub Pages."* 
 I tried deleting the "theme" line in my _config.yml, but the page ends up with only the basic HTML and not the template. I have also installed the gem "Jekyll-remote-theme", but it doesn't seem to help. Can someone help me to figure this out?? Or does this mean that I can't use github pages to host the site?? Thank you very much I am a noob.

Comment: Didi you use your theme from a Gemfile or did you made a git clone from the original repo ?

Comment: @DavidJacquel I used the theme from a Gemfile, ah would that be the problem? If I git clone the repo and put my content back inside, would that help?

Comment: It will help. Just follow https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-clean-blog-jekyll#using-core-files

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer in [adding a theme](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/adding-a-theme-to-your-github-pages-site-using-jekyll#adding-a-theme) in the help docs, hope it helps. In the  `_config.yml` file:

> To use a supported theme, type `theme: THEME-NAME`, replacing THEME-NAME with the name of the theme as shown in the README of the theme's repository
>
> To use any other Jekyll theme hosted on GitHub, type `remote_theme: THEME-NAME`, replacing THEME-NAME with the name of the theme as shown in the README of the theme's repository.